# How to get last data group by each id

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel

How can I get last date data from each `user_id`  :

**User**

```
id |  name   |
1  |  name 1 |
2  |  name 2 |
3  |  name 3 |
```

**Date**

```
id |  date       |  user_id  |
1  |  2018-08-13 |    1      |
2  |  2018-08-13 |    2      |
3  |  2018-08-15 |    1      |
4  |  2018-08-14 |    2      |
```

How can I output like this :

```
user_id |  date       |  name
    1   |  2018-08-15 |  name 1
    2   |  2018-08-14 |  name 2
    3   |  null       |  name 3
```

**UPDATE**

I want my output to select date table join by user table -> and get the last date from each `user_id`  If my `user_id` doesn't have in date value it will output `0` or `null`

Comment: Please give more information about what kind of output you want to get... You want to get the maximum date for each user?

Comment: @MarcinMagdziarz I updated sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For getting just maximum date for user, you can use this one -

```
SELECT
  u.id,
  u.name,
  MAX(d.date) date
FROM user u
  LEFT JOIN date d
    ON u.id = d.user_id
GROUP BY u.id
```

---

```
1   name 1  15-Aug-18
2   name 2  14-Aug-18
3   name 3  (null)
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you're tagging Laravel I suggest to you using the Query Builder like :

```
DB::table('dates')
    ->join('users', 'dates.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
    ->select(db::raw('users.name, user_id, max(date)'))
    ->groupBy('user_id','name')
    ->get();
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
Illuminate\Support\Collection {#2957
     all: [
       {#2944
         +"name": "name 1",
         +"user_id": 1,
         +"max": "2018-08-15",
       },
       {#2941
         +"name": "name 2",
         +"user_id": 2,
         +"max": "2018-08-14",
       },
     ],
   }
```

Comment: Sorry ,Actually I use laravel and I can convert sql to laravel syntax thank you for your answer

Answer (score 1):

You can use `MAX`

```
SELECT u.UserID, MAX(d.date) date, u.name
FROM User u
left join Date d on u.id = d.id
```

Comment: I Updated my question

Answer (score 1):

SELECT u.id,MAX(d.date),u.name FROM DATE d JOIN user u ON d.user_id = u.id GROUP BY d.user_id